# 'rake device' won't work

Tags: ios, rubymotion

This is the error message from the terminal:

```
ERROR:
"Make sure RubyMotion is using a valid (non-expired) provisioning profile
and that no other process (iTunes, Xcode) is connected to your iOS device
at the same time (even through Wi-Fi).
Error when connecting to device: code -402653052
Make sure RubyMotion is using a valid (non-expired) provisioning profile
and that no other process (iTunes, Xcode) is connected to your iOS device
at the same time (even through Wi-Fi)."
Well, neither iTunes nor Xcode was in action nor connected and I had not made any change in the provisioning profile.
```

When I use `motion device-console` the error is similar:

```
Error when pairing device: code -402653172
Make sure RubyMotion is using a valid (non-expired) provisioning profile
and that no other process (iTunes, Xcode) is connected to your iOS device
at the same time (even through Wi-Fi).
```

I've recreated my provisioning-development certificate (and others) several times but it didn't change anything.

I hope very much that someone can help.

Thanks a lot!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I started making certain that I follow this process when connecting my device, and almost never see the problem any more.

1. Turn off wifi on the device
2. Plug in the device
3. Either let the sync finish, or kill it, and disconnect device from iTunes
4. Quit iTunes (also Xcode. Never have that running)

Then you can proceed with the whole recreating the profile:

rake device recreate_profile=1

At that point, it should set up your device, and then you are good to go.  If you see the problem again, you should just follow those 4 steps from above, and it'll be all good.

Comment: Thanks wndxiori - unfortunately it did not work, still the same problem.

Comment: @danielo007 I would suggest that you file a bug with Hipbyte then.  If you are on the "free" version, and don't have access to official bug support, then I'd try posting on http://community.rubymotion.com, because the Hipbyte devs read those.

Comment: thanks - I will do that. However, before I will reinstall os x from scratch with only the main programs so that I can exclude the chance that the reason lies there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you didn't create and use the right Provisioning Profile for your app.

Open Xcode and create an iOS project, go to the Project's TARGETS > General setting page，set the value of properties in the `Identify` section exactly the same as the app properties in Rakefile，select the proper Team and check `Automatically manage signing` in the "Signing" section.

Xcode will create a new Provisioning Profile placed in the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory, config your rubymotion app in the Rakefile to use that Provisioning Profiles.

Comment: This is a RubyMotion project. Xcode use is not required or recommended.

Comment: That's only way I know to solve this problem. Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: We use the motion-provisioning gem (https://github.com/HipByte/motion-provisioning) for simple configuration and command-line provisioning.